# Simple play/scala benchmark, rendering a view versus a raw text output comparison

Tags: scala, playframework

I was just benchmarking a new play/scala application.

When performing a simple text output in my action, I get **60K** requests per second.

If I render a view (see below), it drops to **13K** per second.
Since views are just functions in scala, I would have expected that the extra overhead of calling a function wouldn't drop the requests per second down so dramatically.

I only ran the benchmark for **10-30 seconds,** would it take longer for the jvm to optimize maybe or this is just expected behavour?

```
def index() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok("hello")
}
```

If I actually render a view, the requests per second drops to about **13K**.

```
def index() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(views.html.index())
}
```

/app/views/index.scala.html

```
@()

@main("Welcome to Play") {
  <h1>Welcome to Play!</h1>
}
```

/app/views/main.scala.html

```
@*
 * This template is called from the `index` template. This template
 * handles the rendering of the page header and body tags. It takes
 * two arguments, a `String` for the title of the page and an `Html`
 * object to insert into the body of the page.
 *@
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        @* Here's where we render the page title `String`. *@
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png")">

    </head>
    <body>
        @* And here's where we render the `Html` object containing
         * the page content. *@
        @content

      <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/main.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: View is a function, but it is not a trivial function. I performs string concatenation and also invokes `routes.Assets.versioned` three times. Try rendering a view, which only contains `hello` string.

Comment: Also make sure to properly handle the warmup, as view is fully compiled in dev mode when app is started ("views are just functions in scala" ... View in twirl, as there are othertemplates engines)

Comment: @cchantep I'm using play so its twirl.  Meaning to make sure I'm running in prod you mean?

Comment: I mean that except if you run the bench against a staged app, aka running from SBT, the view is not yet compiled when the app starts, so there is a warmup concern as for benchmarking to be taken in account

Comment: @ygor i removed the asset references and I got it back to 35K thanks!

Comment: Someone already noticed this before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254620/why-play-framework-2-4-is-so-slow-when-using-routes-assets-versioned-in-twirl?rq=1, maybe I will give it a try and do some profiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already said in my comment, the view is not a trivial function. It performs string concatenation and it also calls `routes.Assets.versioned` three times. Profiling session shows, that the view basically only waits on this function:

[image]

Drilling down, we learn, that the `versioned` function always re-reads the file from classpath:

[image]

Maybe you can open an issue and ask Play framework creators, whether serving of assets could be optimized better ?

**Edit**: I profiled two setups. First I modified `HomeControllerSpec` test:

```
"render the index page from a new instance of controller" in {
  val controller = new HomeController(stubControllerComponents())
  val indexAction = controller.index()
  val fakeRequest = FakeRequest(GET, "/")

  var i = 100000
  while (i > 0) {
    indexAction.apply(fakeRequest)
    i -= 1
  }
```

But this does not rule out, that some components can behave differently in production mode. So I ran `sbt stage` and started generated application, attached profiler to running JVM and executed 10000 requests to the profiled JVM. Result was identical though.

Comment: I performed two profiling sessions - more details in edit of the answer